# Show that the estimator of variance is unbiased

Tags: probability

Let $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ be a sample from an exponential distribution with a parameter $\frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Show that $\hat \lambda^2 =\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2$ is an unbiased estimator for the variance of a population.

---

Basically I need to show that $E\hat \lambda^2 = \lambda^2$, which is a simple consequence of the equality: $EX_i^2=D^2X_i+(EX_i)^2=2\lambda^2$.

Comment: Your argument is correct. I am not entirely happy about the use of the letter $\lambda$ here, since the canonical exponential has parameter usually called $\lambda$.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Maybe post an answer?

Comment: There is a complete answer in your post. It would not be reasonable to duplicate it.